# Filtering nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a Vue project and need to search an array with nested objects for a specific object and then return it. The user has a text input field for searching and the search should target "title".

The data looks like this:

```
const data = 
[{
    "catId": "1",
    "catTitle": "a",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "111",
        "title": "aaa"
    }, {
        "id": "222",
        "title": "bbb"
    }, {
        "id": "333",
        "title": "ccc"
    }]
}, {
    "catId": "2",
    "catTitle": "b",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "444",
        "title": "ddd"
    }, {
        "id": "555",
        "title": "eee"
    }]
}, {
    "catId": "3",
    "catTitle": "c",
    "exampleArray": []
}, {
    "catId": "4",
    "catTitle": "d",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "555",
        "title": "fff"
    }]
}]
```

I have tried:

```
return data.filter(item => {
                    return item.catArray.filter(category=> {
                        return category.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                    })
                })
```

e.g. if user input is "aaa", should return:

```
[{
    "catId": "1",
    "catTitle": "a",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "111",
        "title": "aaa"
    }]
}]
```

The search should also return all matching results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

```js
const data = 
[{
    "catId": "1",
    "catTitle": "a",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "111",
        "title": "aaa"
    }, {
        "id": "222",
        "title": "bbb"
    }, {
        "id": "333",
        "title": "ccc"
    }]
}, {
    "catId": "2",
    "catTitle": "b",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "444",
        "title": "ddd"
    }, {
        "id": "555",
        "title": "eee"
    }]
}, {
    "catId": "3",
    "catTitle": "c",
    "exampleArray": []
}, {
    "catId": "4",
    "catTitle": "d",
    "exampleArray": [{
        "id": "555",
        "title": "fff"
    }]
}];
const search = "aa";

console.log(data.filter(item => {
                    return item.exampleArray.some(category=> {
                        return category.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                    })
                }));
                
console.log(data.map(item => {
                    item.exampleArray =  item.exampleArray.filter(category=> {
                        return category.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                    })
                    return item;
                }).filter(a=>a.exampleArray.length>0))
```

All I did is add a check for the length after your filter. Because filter expects true or false to know if the element should be included. While it returns an array with results, an empty array is a truthy value. You need to check if the array has elements to filter correctly.

EDIT: I changed to using FIND instead of FILTER. Find will return falsy value if nothing is found, while returning a truthy value (the found element) if something is found. This would have the benefit of not looping through the whole array, stopping as soon as we found something.

EDIT AGAIN: `some` is the function you want, we learn every day! It does the same as find but instead returns true directly!

Comment: On a side note, instead of filter/some you could have used find, thinking about it I think it would be best.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of the nested `filter(...).length > 0`. It has the same effect, but is more concise and efficient

Comment: Oh you're right... Reading about it just now, never really used it I really tought it was an alias for filter! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this got me much closer to desired result. Only problem still is that if search term is e.g. 'aa' , I get all of these as a result from exampleArray: 

`[{"id": "111", "title": "aaa"}, { "id": "222", "title": "bbb"}, {"id": "333", "title": "ccc"}]`

Where the expected outcome is only:

`[{"id": "111","title": "aaa"}]`

Comment: I did not understand it that way, I have edited the code snippet to add a new console log to have the behaviour you ask. What I did is filter all "exampleArray" elements on the requested search string and then filter all elements that have empty "exampleArray"

Comment: Final question. Currently this mutates the original array. I've tried to implement object spread to not mutate the original array. How could I implement this?

Comment: at the start of the map, `item = Object.assign({},item);` But this is getting way out of the scope of the Original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Live Demo **:**

```js
const data = [{
  "catId": "1",
  "catTitle": "a",
  "exampleArray": [{
    "id": "111",
    "title": "aaa"
  }, {
    "id": "222",
    "title": "bbb"
  }, {
    "id": "333",
    "title": "ccc"
  }]
}, {
  "catId": "2",
  "catTitle": "b",
  "exampleArray": [{
    "id": "444",
    "title": "ddd"
  }, {
    "id": "555",
    "title": "eee"
  }]
}, {
  "catId": "3",
  "catTitle": "c",
  "exampleArray": []
}, {
  "catId": "4",
  "catTitle": "d",
  "exampleArray": [{
    "id": "555",
    "title": "fff"
  }]
}];

const searchWord = 'aaa';

const res = data.filter(obj => {
  obj.exampleArray = obj.exampleArray.filter(({ title }) => title.includes(searchWord))
  return obj.exampleArray.length;
});

console.log(res);
```